# Dependency injection against a private property

Tags: spring, spring-boot

[image]

[image]

But what about this:

```
@Service
public class DatabaseAccountService implements AccountService {

    private final RiskAssessor riskAssessor;

    public DatabaseAccountService(RiskAssessor riskAssessor) {
        this.riskAssessor = riskAssessor;
    }

    // ...

}
```

This example is from the documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html

Maybe I have not understood even the question. Could you comment?

Answer (score 1):

In Spring there are at least 2 different ways for dependency injection: constructor injection and field injection. (leaving setter injection aside for now)

**Constructor injection** is the recommended way to do dependency injection:

```java
@Service
public class DatabaseAccountService {

    private final RiskAssessor riskAssessor;

    @Autowired // annotation is not required in recent Spring versions
    public DatabaseAccountService(RiskAssessor riskAssessor) {
        this.riskAssessor = riskAssessor;
    }

}
```

The referenced Spring documentation also shows an example for constructor injection, simply because it's the recommended way.

**Field injection** is used to inject dependencies directly into fields/properties as mentioned in the question.

```java
@Service
public class DatabaseAccountService {

    @Autowired // don't do this at home or work
    private RiskAssessor riskAssessor;

    public DatabaseAccountService() {
        // RiskAssessor does not appear as constructor parameter
    }

}
```

With the question in video "Can you use dependency injection against a (private) property?" they want to point exactly to field injection maybe to show the possibilities of Spring.
However, they also say that this is bad practice. The blog post [Why field injection is evil](http://www.odrotbohm.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) explains why this is bad practice.

Comment: I can't understand you. Is it an answer to my question? I suppose, you answered some other question. Like how can I use DI in Spring. But my question was only about private properties.

Comment: The code example in your question shows constructor injection. The question/answer in the video is about field injection. I hope this makes the difference a little clearer.

Comment: I can't understand anything. Do you really answer my question?

Comment: I edited my answer and try to be more specific. Please let me know if something remains unclear to you.